# How to select 2nd row of table and enter data in column if 2nd row is contains data, then it selects column of 3rd row using cypress devextreme table

Tags: cypress, chai, mochawesome

**Want to enter data:**
[image: Table Image and source code]

**My Code:**
[image: My cypress code]

I want to select 2nd row of table and enter data in column because 1st row is disable and if 2nd row contains then it auto clicks on 3rd row. My code selects 1st row every time

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] so that your question can be mostly understandable even without looking at the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is selecting the first, uneditable row every time because it contains the same class as your row to select. If `cy.get()` returns multiple elements, then the first one is yielded to the subsequent commands if a specific element is not specified. So, we can get around this by specifying `.eq()`.

```js
cy.get('#TWGanttArea')
  .find('.taskEditRow') // use find, because get always starts from root
  .eq(1) // yields the returned element at the index-0'd 1 position
  .find('td.taskTitle') // finds child elements of type td with class taskTitle
  .type('foo');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `cy.get().get()` sequence like that, because the 2nd `.get()` starts searching at the `<body>` element and ignores the first `cy.get()`.

The correct sequence for your test is `cy.get().find()` because `.find()` *does* start it's search from the result of the previous `cy.get()`.

To locate the empty row, you can use `.emptyRow` class in the selector.

```js
cy.get('#TWGanttArea')
  .find('tr.emptyRow')
  .find('td.taskTitle')
```

With DevExtreme DataGrid you have to click the cell before you can edit data.

```js
cy.get('#TWGanttArea')
  .find('tr.emptyRow')
  .find('td.taskTitle')
  .click()                    // edit mode
  .type('some data here')       // data entry
```

The DataGrid may modify the DOM after clicking, in which case you may get "detached" error.

If that happens, use an alias to perform the steps.

```js
cy.get('#TWGanttArea')
  .find('tr.emptyRow')
  .find('td.taskTitle')
  .as('editCell')

cy.get('@editCell').click()                    // edit mode

cy.get('@editCell').type('some data here')       // data entry
```